# npm install fsevents on ubuntu says unsupported platform

Tags: npm, fsevents

When i try `npm install fsevents` I get

```
Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.1.2:
wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
...
webpack: Failed to compile.

The server does start at localhost:4200

but all `get`s fails with cannot get
```

Not sure how to fix

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this issue (Ubuntu 19.04) by using:

```
npm install node-sass
```

and then

```
npm serve
```

This fixed the issue and `npm serve` now brings up the server without error and the application functions correctly.

```
...
webpack: Compiled Succesfully
```

and now

```
localhost:4200 for this app works correctly
```